# Spring JPA: avoid select before update

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

currently we are working on optimizing JPA queries.

In one of use, we know that update operation expected to be performed and calling save(entity) method of JPA.

However, whenever we are calling this api, select statement is getting executed before update query.

can you please suggest how to avoid such select statement execution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use JPQL(or native SQL) with [`@Query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query).

```
@Repository
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    @Query("update MyEntity as e set e.message = :message where e.id = :id")
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    void updateWithoutSelect(long id, String message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for solution. It works. However, can you please redirect me JPA doc which suggest suggested behaviour ?